# Why do I get  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int Role = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Role"].ToString());
   try
   {
       if (Role != 3)
       {
           gv_ViewApplicants.Visible = true;
           gv_ViewApplicants_SelectedIndexChanged(this, new EventArgs());
       }
       else
       {
           gv_ViewApplicants.Visible = false;
       }
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException e1)
    { 

    }

 }
```

Comment: .Net C# - here is you reply. Your "question" seem to be missing actual question part... only request to "reply .net C#".

Comment: Where exactly does this error occur?

Comment: stop asking for the stack, stop helping within this scenario - the op should put some effort into his/her issue and follow the magic "What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?"-topic ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
int Role = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Role"] != null ?
                           Request.QueryString["Role"].ToString() : 
                           "0");
```

instead of

```
int Role = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Role"].ToString());
```

You need to check for null if not passed query string.

Answer (score 1):

The code is trying to access a member of a reference type variable that is set to null.

Please make source `Request.QueryString["Role"]` is not null.

Comment: all you do is guessing ... without a stack you can't give a qualified answer. the truth is: it could also be `gv_ViewApplicants` or something in `gv_ViewApplicants_SelectedIndexChanged`-method which is null ...

Answer (score 1):

first thing

int Role = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Role"].ToString());

This statement is outside try so if it crashes on QueryString being null or even if Convert.ToInt32 method throw exception, catch block will not be executed.

You can try this code

```
  int number;
  bool result = Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["Role"], out number);
  if (result)
  {
    // your implemntation       
  }
  else
  {        
    // your implemntation   
  }
```

You can even use Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Role"]) if still u are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

You should **Never** catch `NullReferenceException`.

However, the problem seems to be in very first line: (the only line outside `try` block)

```
int Role = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Role"].ToString());
```

either `Request` is null OR `QueryString["Role"]` is returning `null`.

Share the stack trace for more clear answer.

Comment: as the op does not provide a stack, it could also be the catch-scope he is dealing with ... so `gv_ViewApplicants` could also be null, or something in the `gv_ViewApplicants_SelectedIndexChanged`-method

Comment: if that was the case, wouldn't it be caught without any notification?

Comment: the scenario is very unclear. the op could have set a breakpoint in the catch-scope. it's not clear if the exception bubbles to the ui or not ... so ... anything could be ...